# 'new' is creating an array of nulls instead of an array of empty valued class

Tags: c#, arrays, class, struct, null

I have a class

```
namespace MyClassNameSpace {
   public struct a {
       public float Time;
       public float High;
   }
   public class SoC {
       public string Name;
       public a[] Stock =new a[9];
   }
```

}

And in Form1 I create an array of SoC:

```
public static SoC[] b = new SoC[5];
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    b[1].Name = "ABC"
}
```

The problem is that `b` is an array of nulls instead of being an array of `empty` (zeroed) SoC... How do I change that?

Answer (score 9):

You are creating an array of reference variables of *Reference (class)* type. The statement,

```
public static SoC[] b = new SoC[5];
```

creates **5** reference variables whose initial value is null.

This way you can create objects:

```
for(int i=0;i<b.Length;i++) {
    b[i]=new SoC();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Allocating space for the array doesn't actually create the objects. You need to loop through and call the constructor for each item.